# create superuser... How can I create a super user if I can't access the single super user account?

Tags: postgresql

I use postgresql. It says the only existing superuser is ibm... but I did not create this superuser and according to the documentation:

"The ibm account is the only superuser on your deployment. A superuser account is not available for you to us. This user is an internal administrative account that manages the stability of your deployment."

How can I create a super user if I can't access the single super user account?

[users db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNCEA.png)

Version: PostgreSQL 15.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 11.3.1 20221121 (Red Hat 11.3.1-4), 64-bit

Comment: You really expect an answer with a question that basically has no information? Look at your question and ask yourself how someone else is supposed to get any useful from it? Then update the question to include the information needed to troubleshoot this.

Comment: That's my first question here. So don't be rude and go easy on me

Comment: This question would be a problem wherever it was asked. The issue is it provides no useful information for anyone else to work on to provide an answer. Again, update the question with the basics of your setup and what documentation you are referring to.

Comment: PostgreSQL 15.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 11.3.1 20221121 (Red Hat 11.3.1-4), 64-bit

Comment: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/databases-for-postgresql?topic=databases-for-postgresql-user-management&interface=ui#user-management-ibm-users

Comment: Fortunately you can't: It would be a massive security breach if a non-superuser would be able to create a superuser. The documentation from your cloud provider (IBM in this case) is also pretty clear about this: `The ibm account is the only superuser on your deployment. A superuser account is not available for you to us. This user is an internal administrative account that manages the stability of your deployment.`. If you need a superuser, you have to host and maintain the cluster yourself. Not some could provider

Answer (score 1):

You are apparently using a vendor-provided DBaaS.

> A superuser account is not available for you to use.

Full stop.  They are the superuser, you are not.  If you want to be the superuser, don't use this DBaaS.